# Does WinUI need .NET?

Tags: winui

According to Microsoft, WinUI is the UI part of the Windows App SDK.
Am I correct in assuming that Windows App SDK is only for developing Windows 10 and 11 applications and does not need .NET at all?

Answer (score 0):

> Does WinUI need .NET?

No

> Am I correct in assuming that Windows App SDK is only for developing Windows 10 and 11 applications and does not need .NET at all?

Yes.

The Windows App SDK and the WinUI is not implemented in or part of .NET.

WinUI is a *native* user interface (UI) framework for Windows desktop apps, including native apps that use C++ with the Win32 API (and also managed apps that use C# and .NET).

The Windows App SDK is currently supported on Windows 11 and downlevel to Windows 10, version 1809.